# Trying to pass url in form action

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django and i'm stuck now.
I'm trying to pass the url in form [action] attribute that would go to my edit function defined in [views.py] file and do it's job but whenever I try to pass the url [NoReverseMatch] is shown.

This is what i tried to do:

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="editform" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-content">
      <div class = "modal-header">
        <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">
          <b>Edit Information</b>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class = "modal-body">
        <form action="{% url 'studentapp:editrow' rowid=id %}" id="editform" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "your_name">
              Your name:
            </label>
            <input class = "form-control" id="new_name" type = "text" name="name" value="{{ student_detail.name }}" placeholder="Enter your name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for = "course_name">
              Course:
            </label>
            <input id="new_course" class = 'form-control' type = "text" name="course" value="{{ student_detail.course }}" placeholder="Enter your course">
          </div>
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "rollno">
              Roll No.:
            </label>
            <input id="new_rollno" type = "text" class = 'form-control' name="roll" value="{{ student_detail.roll }}" placeholder="Enter your roll number">
          </div>
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for ="addr">
              Address:
            </label>
            <input id="new_address" type = "text" name="address" class = 'form-control' value="{{ student_detail.address }}" placeholder="Enter your address"/>
          </div>
          <input type = "submit" value="Update" id="update" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my urls.py I've used the following url:

```
url(r'^editrow/(?P<rowid>[0-9]+)/$', views.editrow, name='editrow'),
```

My [editrow] view looks something like this:

```
def editrow(request, rowid):
item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, rowid=id)
print item
if request.method=="POST":
    form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=item)
    if form.is_valid():
        post=form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentapp:index'),rowid.id)
    else:
        form=EntryForm(instance=item)
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
else:
    form=EntryForm(instance=item)
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

View that render's the template:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    latest_student = Studentapp.objects.order_by('pub_date')
    context.update({
        'latest_student': latest_student
    })
    response = {"status": False, "errors": []}
    if request.is_ajax():
        id = request.POST['id']
        response = {}
        response['status'] = False
        student_detail = Studentapp.objects.filter(id=id).first()

        context = {
            "student_detail": student_detail
        }

        template = render_to_string("studentapp/_edit_student.html", context)
        response['template'] = template
        response['status'] = True
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="applicaton/json")

    return render(request, "studentapp/index.html", context)
```

What i'm doing in crud is:
1) make an [edit] button in table through for loop.
2) when i click [edit] button a pre-populated form shows up(which i'm getting).
3) After i click the pre-populated form i want to edit that form and save it and updated data is reflected in my django db.

Comment: Since you use `rowid=id` in your template, you need to make sure that `id` is set in your view/template. If you need more help than that, you need to show the full traceback, which will show where the error is occurring, and the view where the error is occurring.

Comment: return render(request, "studentapp/index.html", context) this is the line traceback is showing

Comment: Then the problem is either in your template or something is missing from `context`.

Comment: I've added template now. can you tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Go back to my original comment. You use `rowid=id` in your template, so you need to make sure that id is set in your view/template.

Comment: i've used rowid=id in both views and template file. still no luck. i've added my views.py also so you can go through that also.

Comment: Showing the rest of the `editrow` view won't help, unless the error is occurring when you access that view (e.g. `http://localhost:8000/editrow/10/`). I'll try one more way to explain - how do you expect `rowid=id` to work if you don't set `id` anywhere?

Comment: @Aditya you would need to show the other view, the one that renders the template, not the view that receives the POST request.

Comment: @Ralf i've added my view. can you please go through it and tell me my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Alasdair, I looked in my code what he was trying to tell me and i got the  answer.
The url that i was trying to pass through my action attribute was wrong. Here's what i did.

```
<form action="{% url 'studentapp:editrow' rowid=student_detail.id %}" id="editform" method="POST">
```

Through "student_detail" i'm able to get pre-populated form as i mentioned above. i used the same to get the id and pass it to my "editrow" view.

It's working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you never add `id` to your context in your view `index`. So the template does not have that variable available.

You need to add that id to your context.
Just like @Alasdair pointed out in the comments.